# use negative loss in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am implementing a reinforcement agent that takes actions based on classes.
so it can take action 1 or 2 or 3 or 4.

So my question is can I use negative loss in tensorflow to stop it from outputting an action.

Example:
Let's say the agent outputs action 1 I want to very strongly dissuade it from taking action 1 in that situation again.  but there is not a known action that it should have taken instead.  So I can't just choose a different action to make it learn that.

So my question is:
does tensorflow gradient computation handle negative values for loss.
And if it does will it work the way I describe?

Answer (score 3):

A gradient descent minimizer will typically try to find the minimum loss irrespective of the sign of the loss surface.  It sounds like you either want to **a)** assign a large loss to encourage your model to pick something else or **b)** assign a fifth *no-action* category.

Comment: "A gradient descent minimizer will typically try to find the minimum loss irrespective of the sign of the loss surface." does that mean that 1) it will try to make the loss as small of a number as possible i.e. converging loss to -INF OR 2) it will try to make the loss be as close to zero as possible regardless of sign?

Comment: @ZsoltSafrany - The gradient is the direction of maximum rate of change, i.e. the vector derivative of the scalar loss function.  Derivatives are sensitive to rate of change of a function, not constant offsets.  So 1), it should make the loss as small as possible.